# XDocument null reference on object that isnt null

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml (called xdoc) file like the following:

```
<Root>
<ItemContainer>
<Item>
<Item>
<Item>
<Item>
</ItemContainer>
</Root>
```

if i do the following

```
XElement xel = xdoc.Element("ItemContainer");
```

As far as i understand, i should get back a reference to to my ItemContainer node element, but i keep getting back null. Ive read the msdn docs for this

> "Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified
>   XName. "

as far as i can see, ItemContainer is the first child element with the specified name. What am i missing?

Comment: Is `xdoc` not maybe `null`? Make sure `xdoc` was loaded... How do you populate `xdoc`?

Comment: `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\projects\gen\test_xml.xml");` Ive put a breakpoint on xdoc and everything has loaded as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do :

```
XElement xel = xdoc.Root.Element("ItemContainer");
```

Because, the `<Root>` has also to be handled.

```
XElement xel = xdoc.Element("Root").Element("ItemContainer");
```

should also work

Answer (score 1):

I assume `xdoc` is of type `XDocument`. The only child element of the document is the root node `<Root>`.
Because of this, your code should look like this:

```
XElement xel = xdoc.Root.Element("ItemContainer");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ...

```
xdoc.Root.Element("ItemContainer");
```

The root element is the first element

Answer (score 1):

As others explained, the only child of an `XDocument` is the root element, so to get to a child of the root, you have to get through the root:

```
XElement xel = xdoc.Root.Element("ItemContainer");
```

Alternatively, you can use [`XElement.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435.aspx), if you don't need to access things like XML declaration. It returns the root element directly:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"c:\projects\gen\test_xml.xml");
XElement xel = root.Element("ItemContainer");
```